# how does map works in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am new to Python programming. I encountered a way to take a list input using map.

code 1:

```
l = list(map(int, input().split()))
print(l)
```

code 2:

```
l = [map(int, input().split())]
print(l)
```

Both of them look identical to me,

But when I took the input `1 2 3 4`, code #1 gave the output `[1,2,3,4]`
and code #2 for the same input gave the output `[<map object at 0x0000024DFD85F0C8>]`.

What is the difference between both methods? How are they different? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `list(map(...))` will convert map object to list. `[map(...)]` will store the map object in a list

Comment: "but when i took input ..." - please provide the code (to make your question as specific as possible)

Comment: Welp, I see, `map()` is easier to type than `do_this_operation_on_every_element_of_the_list(operation, the_list)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What [`list()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list) does is it takes any iterable like generator, tuple, string, map etc. and exhousts given object to create list. For example:

```
gen = (i**2 for i in range(10))  # -> <generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f5b7066e0f8>
list(gen)  # -> [0, 1, 4, 9]

tup = (1, 2, 3, 4)  # -> (1, 2, 3, 4)
list(tup)  # -> [1, 2, 3, 4]

str_ = '123'  # -> '123'
list(str_)  # -> ['1', '2', '3']
```

You can think of it as:

```
def list(it):
    ret_list = []
    for el in it:
        ret_list.append(el)
    return el
```

---

Where as surrounding instances with `[...]` simply creates list with whatever you've passed, so:

```
gen = (i**2 for i in range(10))  # -> <generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f5b7066e0f8>
[gen]  # -> [<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f5b7066e0f8>]

tup = (1, 2, 3, 4)  # -> (1, 2, 3, 4)
[tup]  # -> [(1, 2, 3, 4)]

str_ = '123'  # -> '123'
[str_]  # -> ['123']
```

Naive implementation:

```
def brancets(*args):
    ret_list = []
    for arg in args:
        ret_list.append(arg)
    return ret_list

# [1, 2, 3] -> brackets(1, 2, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

The map() function executes a specified function for each item in a iterable. The item is sent to the function as a parameter.
you have to specify the function to execute in each item.
to display the final result you can use "list" for readability
this is an example:

```
def myfunc(a, b):
   return a + b

x = map(myfunc, ('apple', 'banana', 'cherry'), ('orange', 'lemon', 'pineapple'))
print(x)
print(list(x)) #for readability
```

in your case you can do this

```
def myfunc(a)
   return int(a)*2
x = map(myfunc,input().split())
print (list(x))
```

check this link : https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_map.asp